# angular directive restrict M not work

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

There is an directive restrict M as followed code. But nothing outputed on page. What's wrong? Thanks!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="app">
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="lib/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var app = angular.module('app',[]);
        app.controller('indexCtrl',function($scope){

        });
        app.directive('di',function(){
            return{
                restrict:"M",
                template:'abc'
            };
        })
    </script>
</head>
<body ng-controller="indexCtrl">
<!-- directive:di -->
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two things:

- The template needs to enclose within an HTML tag
- Add a `replace: true` property to the directive, to replace custom `di` with the HTML template

```js
var app = angular.module('app', []);
app.controller('indexCtrl', function($scope) {

});

app.directive('di', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'M',
    template: '<p>abc</p>',
    replace: true
  };
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="app">

<body ng-controller="indexCtrl">
  <!-- directive:di -->
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: It works! Thank you!!! But I only change 'abc' to '<div>abc</div>' and 'replace' property has been deprecated on official document. : )

Comment: *'replace' property has been deprecated on official document*, can you share the source for this information?

Comment: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile , search `replace` section and you will see it. https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile#-replace-deprecated-will-be-removed-in-next-major-release-i-e-v2-0-

Comment: I found `replace` property is nessesary for displaying comment directive but it also has been deprecated. haha

Answer (score 0):

I have made small changes in you code and it worked. I have added *replace : true* in the directive, And modified template parameter as *html content*.

*Code:*

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="app">
<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var app = angular.module('app',[]);
        app.controller('indexCtrl',function($scope){

       });
        app.directive('di',function(){
            return{
                restrict:"M",
                replace : true,
                template:'<b>abc</b>'
            };
        })
    </script>
</head>
<body ng-controller="indexCtrl">
<!-- directive:di -->
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I shoud point out that `replace` property has been deprecated in recent version. https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile#-replace-deprecated-will-be-removed-in-next-major-release-i-e-v2-0-